# Pair elements from lists of list to form a new list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists like the following,

```
a = [[ [1,2], [10, 3]], [[4,5], [6, 7]]]
```

I need to pair the inner most list elements this way,

```
a = [[[1, 10], [2, 3]], [[4, 6], [5, 7]]].
```

The straighforward approach would be the following,

```
pairings_ = []
for ind in a:
    pairings_.append([[x, y] for x in ind[0] for y in ind[1])
```

This would cause memoryerror if the lists inside ind are more than 2.
For example, 
If there were three inner lists in ind[0], [1, 2], [10, 3], [7, 8], then the pairing would be  [1, 10, 7] and [2, 3, 8]. 
The assumption is the length of inner list of [[1, 10], [2, 3]]  and  [[4,6], [5, 7]] will always be equal.

How would I go about doing this in the most pythonic / numpy / efficient way possible?

Comment: so you just want to switch 5s and 6s? The objective here is a little unclear

Comment: if one array has 3 elements and rest has 2 elements, what do you want to do with the remaining element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I go about doing this in the most pythonic / numpy / efficient way possible?

You can use [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) and convert it back to list.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np


In [2]: a = [[ [1,2], [10, 3]], [[4,5], [6, 7]]]


In [3]: np.transpose(a, (0,2,1)).tolist()

Out[3]: [[[1, 10], [2, 3]], [[4, 6], [5, 7]]]
```

Answer (score 5):

`list(zip(*x))` is a well known idiom for 'transposing' lists.  In your case:

```
In [267]: a = [[ [1,2], [10, 3]], [[4,5], [6, 7]]]                              
In [268]: [list(zip(*row)) for row in a]                                        
Out[268]: [[(1, 10), (2, 3)], [(4, 6), (5, 7)]]
```

Array `transpose` is convenient and expressive, but creating an array from a list can be expensive.

```
In [272]: timeit [list(zip(*row)) for row in a]                                 
1.58 µs ± 23.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [273]: timeit np.transpose(a, (0,2,1)).tolist()                              
11.8 µs ± 217 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Removing the array creating from the timing loop:

```
In [274]: %%timeit arr = np.array(a) 
     ...: np.transpose(arr, (0,2,1))                                                               
1.47 µs ± 11.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

But as always with these timing comparisons, results may differ when working with larger lists.

Comment: `[[*map(list,zip(*row))] for row in a]` to get only lists. It's not much slower.